# move and rotate an image with fingers on a view ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, move

### Moving and rotating an image with finger's

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
    [self.view addSubview: self.imageview];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This code is to move image

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    self.imageview.center = touchLocation;
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get touch event

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.PlayVideo];

    if ([touch view] == self.view)
    {

        self.imageview.center = touchLocation;


    }
}
```

This code is to rotate image (T dropped a rotation gesture on to the image and draghed on to .h file)

```
- (IBAction)regRotation:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"rotation");
    CGFloat netRotation =0.0;
    CGFloat rotation =[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender rotation];
    CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation+netRotation);
    sender.view.transform=transform;
    if(sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        netRotation+=rotation;
    }
}
```

---

The image is moving and not perfectly rotating

Comment: What do you mean by "not perfectly rotating"? What does it do exactly, and what are you expecting?

Comment: My program is moving an rotating an image over a video. when i use the above code image is moving and rotating but its not moving and rotating perfectly

Comment: when i start rotating its moving to some where else on the story bord and rotating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    CGFloat firstX;
    CGFloat firstY;
    CGFloat lastRotation;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
lastRotation = 0.0;
            self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
            [self.view addSubview: self.imageview];
            [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
        [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [self.imageview addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

 UIRotationGestureRecognizer* rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
    [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

        }

    -(void)move:(id)sender {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
        CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

        if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
            firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
        }
        translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

        [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

        if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

            CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (0*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.imageview].x);
            CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (0*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.imageview].y);

            [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
        }
    }
-(void)rotate:(id)sender {

    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageview.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

    [self.imageview setTransform:newTransform];
    lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}
```

Its working for me..

Comment: [img_object1 addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer]; what is img_object1

Comment: img_object1 is self.imageview for your coding. :)

Comment: remove -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event and - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event methods

Comment: @PradipVanparia From your code Rotation is done. Only Movement of object is happend. Is it correct solution ? Or I am forgotting anything ?

Comment: @Abha are you using Autolayout in your project?

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 answer for Pan, Zoom and Rotate:

```
var lastRotation : CGFloat = 0.0
var previousScale : CGFloat = 1.0
var beginX : CGFloat = 0.0
var beginY : CGFloat = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.rotate(sender:)))
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.scale(sender:)))
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.pan(sender:)))
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc func rotate(sender : Any){
    if let sender = sender as? UIRotationGestureRecognizer, let imageView = self.imageView{
        if sender.state == .ended{
            lastRotation = 0.0
            return
        }
        let rotation : CGFloat = 0.0 - (lastRotation - sender.rotation)
        let currentTransform = imageView.transform
        let newTransform = currentTransform.rotated(by: rotation)
        imageView.transform = newTransform
        lastRotation = sender.rotation
    }
}

@objc func scale(sender : Any){
    if let sender = sender as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer, let imageView = self.imageView{
        if sender.state == .ended{
            previousScale = 1.0
            return
        }
        let newScale = 1.0 - (previousScale - sender.scale)
        let currentTransform = imageView.transform
        let newTransform = currentTransform.scaledBy(x: newScale, y: newScale)
        imageView.transform = newTransform
        previousScale = sender.scale
    }
}

@objc func pan(sender : Any){
    if let sender = sender as? UIPanGestureRecognizer, let imageView = self.imageView{
        var newCenter = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        if(sender.state == .began){
            beginX = imageView.center.x
            beginY = imageView.center.y
        }
        newCenter = CGPoint.init(x: beginX + newCenter.x, y: beginY + newCenter.y)
        imageView.center = newCenter
    }
}
```